# Chart.js - How to display all bars as different datasets(same behaviour as doughnut)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have been searching around and can't find a solution to disable the view of each individual bar.

I have a bar chart with a wide range of values: [image: Bar-chart]

And I want to be able to toggle the viewing of individual values as one can do in the doughnut chart:  [image: doughnut-char with disabled values]

This doughnut-char is using the same dataset, but I have disabled the top-3 values.

How can this behaviour be applied to the bar-chart?

Edit/Clarification:
With disabling I mean by clicking the corresponding label; as one can do in the doughnut chart: [image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the data from the dataset for the values you wish to remove?

Comment: I want the user to be able to toggle the information, so removing it from viewing will not help; replaced disable with toggle in my question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you'll have to generate custom [HTML legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) using `legendCallback` together with some `CSS`.

```
legendCallback: chart => {
  let html = '<ul>';
  chart.data.labels.forEach((l, i) => {
    const ds = chart.data.datasets[0];
    const bgColor = ds.backgroundColor[i];
    const border = ds.borderWidth + 'px solid ' + ds.borderColor[i];
    html += '<li>' +
      '<span style="width: 36px; height: 14px; background-color:' + bgColor + '; border:' + border + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">&nbsp;</span>' +
      '<span id="legend-label-' + i + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">' +
      (Array.isArray(l) ? l.join('<br/>') : l) + '</span>' +
      '</li>';
  });
  return html + '</ul>';
},
```

> To make this behave the same as standard Chart.js charts, the function `onLegendClicked` is invoked when a mouse click occurs on a legend label. This function redefines `data.labels` and the `dataset` (`data`, `backgroundColor` and `borderColor`) by keeping trak of the hidden state of individual bars. It also changes the legend labels text style between normal and strike-through.

Please take a look at the following code snippet and see how it works.

```js
const labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
const data = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40];
const backgroundColor = ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"];
const borderColor = ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)"];

const states = labels.map((l, i) => ({index: i, hidden: false}));

function onLegendClicked(e, i) {
  let hidden = !states[i].hidden; 
  states[i].hidden = hidden;  
  let nonHiddenIndexes = states.filter(s => !s.hidden).map(s => s.index);
  chart.data.labels = nonHiddenIndexes.map(i => labels[i]);
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = nonHiddenIndexes.map(i => data[i]);
  chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = nonHiddenIndexes.map(i => backgroundColor[i]);
  chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = nonHiddenIndexes.map(i => borderColor[i]);
  const legendLabelSpan = document.getElementById("legend-label-" + i);
  legendLabelSpan.style.textDecoration = hidden ? 'line-through' : '';
  chart.update();
};

const chart = new Chart("chart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First Dataset",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"],
      borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    legendCallback: chart => {
      let html = '<ul>';
      chart.data.labels.forEach((l, i) => {
        const ds = chart.data.datasets[0];
        const bgColor = ds.backgroundColor[i];
        const border = ds.borderWidth + 'px solid ' + ds.borderColor[i];
        html += '<li>' +
          '<span style="width: 36px; height: 14px; background-color:' + bgColor + '; border:' + border + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">&nbsp;</span>' +
          '<span id="legend-label-' + i + '" onclick="onLegendClicked(event, \'' + i + '\')">' +
          (Array.isArray(l) ? l.join('<br/>') : l) + '</span>' +
          '</li>';
      });
      return html + '</ul>';
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();
```

```css
#legend>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#legend li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
}

#legend li span {
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 500px">
  <div id="legend"></div>
  <canvas id="chart" height="150"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already mention in the title of your question, each bar must be defined in a separate dataset. Also `data.labels` should be defined as an array that contains a single empty string (`[""]`).

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart("chart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: [""],    
    datasets: [{
      label: "A",
      data: [65],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: "B",
      data: [59],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: "C",
      data: [80],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: "D",
      data: [56],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: "E",
      data: [55],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```

**UPDATE (13. May 2021)**

Meanwhile I [**answered**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67520525/2358409) a similar question and improved the code I posted here. This solution is cleaner and now also displays the tick labels on the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you for providing me a working example :) However, the labels under each bar are now missing with this approach and displays empty space on each side of the graphs(This does not nearly look as bad with 5 graphs compared to 10+ graphs)