# Chart.js manipulate each bar in chart with different labels

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, chart.js3

does anyone know if this is possible? Basically I want the chart to have labels for example [Jan, Feb, March] and I want to be able to toggle these values on and off. Seems like such a simple thing but is proving problematic.

Comment: One of these Chart.js v2 related answers may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64389544/2358409 https://stackoverflow.com/a/64328566/2358409

Comment: @uminder the answer you gave on the other question is where I am now, but I wan the [A B C D E ] to be labelled below each bar

Comment: The first link points to an answer that uses a custom HTML legend. It's quite complex but it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate `dataset` for each bar and define the `data` in point format as follows:

```
data: [{ x: 1, y: 16 }]
```

Further you need to define a second x-axis that will contain the labels.

```
{
  offset: true,
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

The `labels` on the second x-axis need to be collected and defined programmatically each time the `hidden` state of a `dataset` changes. This can be done with the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In your case, you can use the `beforeLayout` hook.

```
plugins: [{
  beforeLayout: chart => chart.chart.options.scales.xAxes[1].labels = chart.chart.data.datasets.filter(ds => !ds._meta[0].hidden).map(ds => ds.label)
}]
```

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    beforeLayout: chart => chart.chart.options.scales.xAxes[1].labels = chart.chart.data.datasets.filter(ds => !ds._meta[0].hidden).map(ds => ds.label)
  }],
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'A',
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 16 }],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'B',
        data: [{ x: 2, y: 22 }],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'C',
        data: [{ x: 3, y: 18 }],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'D',
        data: [{ x: 4, y: 13 }],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'E',
        data: [{ x: 5, y: 5 }],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'F',
        data: [{ x: 6, y: 16 }],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title: () => undefined
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
          display: false
        },
        {
          offset: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Also, the solution doesn't work if you have already some datasets hidden from the begging.

Comment: To manage more charts on one page you should use `ds._meta[chart.id]` instead of `ds._meta[0]`