# How do I show 2 legends for a single dataset in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a Javascript program that displays a bar chart of solar energy based on JSON readings provided by [Solcast](https://solcast.com/). For the current day these readings consist of actual values for each half hour before the current time and forecast readings for those values after current time.  I want to show the actual bars in one colour and the forecast bars in another colour.  I can accomplish this easily enough using a single dataset with backgroundColor set to an array that contains the different colours depending on whether it is an actual or forecast reading.

What I want to do is to show a legend for each colour (a double legend) showing what each colour represents.

If I use 2 datasets, both start from the same origin with the initial forecast readings sitting beside the initial actual readings and each bar width is halved.  If I use a second dataset and set its display set to 'none' then the legend text is struck out.

Is there any way that I can have a single dataset with two legends (is HTML Legend the way to go, but I can't find any help on that)?

My (relevant) code is:

```
var intp3 = period[3].replace(":","");
if (intp3 < oldTime) {  //  determine if reading is actual or forecast
  xValues.unshift(period[3]);
  yValues.unshift(forecast);
  barColors.unshift("darkseagreen");
}
else {
  xValues.push(period[3]);
  yValues.push(forecast);
  barColors.push("orange");
}
oldTime = intp3;

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: barColors,
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: barText
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
      position: "top",
      align: "center",
    }
  }
});
```

`

Comment: This may help you find a solution for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67520525/2358409

Comment: Changing the way the legend is displayed in a radical way would require a lot of work; however, the issues you have with using two datasets solution can be overcome, by for instance using the `grouped: false` option in datasets, and possibly setting the x-value label in each dataset - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f63Lk470/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play around and see what I can come up with.